# Symfony2 and Twig: {{ dump() }} causes built-in server crash

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using symfony 2.5.8, and when dumping vars in twig through the command {{ dump(whatever) }}, my computer freezes, and after a while I get an error page and the following error from the console where I started the built-in server (with -v option):

```
Killed
Built-in server terminated unexpectedly
```

Does anyone have had the same problem? Does anyone know what could be the cause?

I already added the following to the configuration in `app/config/config_dev.yml`

```
services:
    custom.twig.extension.debug:
        class: Twig_Extension_Debug
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The built-in server isn't very robust - it's only designed for simple local development. I'd expect it to be OK with dumping small things (simple variables), but chances are you're putting something big in, and it's running out of memory.

Comment: Same thing with apache (Internal server error).
Probably what I want to dump is quite big, but it feels odd that this results in a server crash.

Comment: No var can be dumped? If you try to dump entities you can exceed your memory limit. But try to dump some string or integer var.

Comment: With simple string variables it works fine.

Comment: This can be caused by dumping recursive objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running out of memory and you have installed the `xdebug` module you can set in your php.ini file the option `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100`.

This will truncate the output of your dump and will help you debugging highly-nested objects like doctrine entities with relationships

Comment: Installed php5-xdebug and added the proposed expression in php.ini. Now it does print something!

Answer (score 2):

If the variable that you would like to dump refers to a Doctrine2 entity, it is a common behaviour.

According to the documentation of Twig, dump uses the native var_dump function:

> Internally, Twig uses the PHP var_dump function.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

The Doctrine2 documentation on the other hand says that you can't just var_dump an entity:

> Lazy load proxies always contain an instance of Doctrine’s EntityManager and all its dependencies. Therefore a var_dump() will possibly dump a very large recursive structure which is impossible to render and read. You have to use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump() to restrict the dumping to a human readable level. Additionally you should be aware that dumping the EntityManager to a Browser may take several minutes, and the Debug::dump() method just ignores any occurrences of it in Proxy instances.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html?highlight=var_dump

As a solution you could write a Twig extension that uses Doctrine2's `Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()` method for dumping out entities.

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 2.6, you can `dump()` any object using the [`VarDumper`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html) component.

You should overwrite Twig's `{{ dump() }}` by using an extension (replace namespaces by yours):

<kbd>Fuz/AppBundle/Twig/Extension/DebugExtension.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

class DebugExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array (
              new \Twig_SimpleFunction('dump', array('Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper', 'dump')),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'FuzAppBundle:Debug';
    }

}
```

<kbd>Fuz/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml</kbd>

```
app.twig.debug_extension:
     class: %app.twig.debug_extension.class%
     arguments: []
     tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Symfony just released `var-dumper` and I recommend using this feature in PHP script for a var dump. There is an article for this in Sitepoint: http://www.sitepoint.com/var_dump-introducing-symfony-vardumper/